# Search a named range between two times in Google Sheets and populate the difference

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, named-ranges

I'm trying to create a schedule heat map so that we can adjust staffing times and days.  In order to make this as easy as possible, I've come up with a tabular structure that allows the user to input the employee's name, then select their shift start time and their shift end time from a drop-down, and then use checkboxes to indicate which days they will work, as shown:

[image: Schedule Select table]

The end result would be a heat map that counts the number of instances that a value exists in the range between the start time and end time, broken down by hour and by day.  My original thought was to use `COUNTIFS` thusly: `=COUNTIFS(Calculations!D:D, ">=9:00:00", Sheet9!D:D, "=TRUE")` Where Calculations!D:D is the column of the selected Start Time, where ">=9:00:00" checks to see if the start time is greater than or equal to 9AM, and where Sheet9!D:D, "=TRUE" checks to see if the checkbox for that day is checked.  So this example would check to see if someone is working at 9AM on Monday.

However, this didn't pan out since we're checking for any value greater than 9AM, and most employees won't be working more than 10 hours, so I'm getting false positives.

My next thought was to use a named range that would start at the Start Time value and then, if necessary, loop back through to the End Time (for example, if an employee started at 10PM and their shift ended at 7AM).  Since this range would be dynamic (not all employees will work strictly 8 hours per day), I would need to check to see if **a** value *exists* within the range, however, I'm not sure how to A: Loop through or B: check to see if a value is in the dynamic range.  I assume this will require Google Apps Script to pull off, but I'm not well-versed in it, and I've been beating my head against a wall trying to figure this out.  Any help would be appreciated!

Oh, and here's a screenshot of the desired output, with a couple of values filled in:

[image: Schedule Heat Map]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you wanted but I wanted to practice using times is Google Scripts so I had a crack at solving your problem. However, there are a couple of little bits I didn't have time to write that I've commented in the script.

If I've understood your problem correctly, you want to take a series of shifts life this:

[image]

And convert it into a heatmap like this:

[image]

(I've not done all your formatting, but I'm guessing you want to see how many people are available for every hour of the day)

In my code, I called the first sheet above "Roster" and the second sheet "RosterOverview" - note the capitalisation and lack of spaces.

**Approach**

I wrote two scripts. One (rostering) to check which days a staff member worked and a second to see the hours they worked and update the values in RosterOverview (updateCalendar).

For each member of staff, I took their working hours and working days. I checked to see if they worked on a certain day and, if they did, sent their working hours to a script called updateCalendar. This second script then looked to see if they worked a night shift i.e. over midnight or not. The script then adds a 1 to each hour window a staff member is rostered for.

**The scripts**

```
function rostering() {  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rosterSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Roster");
  var overviewSheet = ss.getSheetByName("RosterOverview");
  var range = rosterSheet.getRange(2,2,4,9);  //You will need to work out how to accurately get this range for your data - 2 and 2 are the starting row and column respectively i.e. B2; 4 indicates the number of rows; 9 indicates the number of columns
  var times = range.getValues();
  var calendarRange = overviewSheet.getRange("B2:I25"); //On RosterOverview, this is the range of cells for Monday-Monday, midnight-2300. You need 8 columns of data because the extra one is for Sunday night overflowing into Monday morning.

//You will need to write a bit of code yourself to make sure all the values in calendarRange are set to 0. I have set this manually and pull them below when I was testing.

  var calendarValues = calendarRange.getValues();

  //This section loops through each staff member's hours and days.
  //It looks to see if the check box is ticked for each day of the week in turn.
  //If a checkbox is ticked, it calls a second script: updateCalendar
  //It's probably possible to write a separate loop to go through the days of the week

  for (var i = 0; i < range.getHeight(); i++){
    //if Monday shift
  if(times[i][2] == true){
    calendarValues = updateCalendar(times[i][0], times[i][1], calendarValues, 0)
  }
    //if Tuesday shift
  if(times[i][3] == true){
    calendarValues = updateCalendar(times[i][0], times[i][1], calendarValues, 1)
  }
  //if Wednesday shift
  if(times[i][4] == true){
    calendarValues = updateCalendar(times[i][0], times[i][1], calendarValues, 2)
  }
  //if Thursday shift
  if(times[i][5] == true){
    calendarValues = updateCalendar(times[i][0], times[i][1], calendarValues, 3)
  }
  //if Friday shift
  if(times[i][6] == true){
    calendarValues = updateCalendar(times[i][0], times[i][1], calendarValues, 4)
  }
  //if Saturday shift
  if(times[i][7] == true){
    calendarValues = updateCalendar(times[i][0], times[i][1], calendarValues, 5)
  }
  //if Sunday shift
  if(times[i][8] == true){
    calendarValues = updateCalendar(times[i][0], times[i][1], calendarValues, 6)
  }

  }
  //Once ithas looped through al the staff member's shifts, it updates the RosterOverview
  //sheet with how many people are on each hour
  calendarRange.setValues(calendarValues);
}

function updateCalendar(startTime, endTime, roster, day){ //Let day be a digit: 0 for Monday, 1 for Tuesday.... Roster is the calendarValues array from the roster function
    if(startTime > endTime){ //night shift over midnight
      for (var j = startTime.getHours(); j < 24; j++){
        roster[j][day] = roster[j][day] + 1;        
      }
      for (var j = 0; j < endTime.getHours(); j++){
        roster[j][day + 1] = roster[j][day + 1] + 1;
      }
    } else {
      for (var j = startTime.getHours(); j < endTime.getHours(); j++){
        roster[j][day] = roster[j][day] + 1;
      }
    }  
    return roster;
}
```

**What you need to do**

1. It's probably best to add a custom menu so you can run it from the sheet: see this Fundamentals codelab to learn how: https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-3#0
2. You need to make sure your Google Sheet and the Google script are set to the same timezone. To set the timezone for the script, from the script editor you want to click on [Use legacy editor] in the top right hand corner then go to File > Project properties. Once set, return to the new editor.
3. You will need to write a little bit of code that selects the range of data for your staff members' shifts and a bit of code that resets the RosterOverview spreadsheet values to 0s before you run the script again.

Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Just realised that if you have a shift that ends at midnight the script will update the wrong day with the hours. For reasons that don't quite make sense to me (despite writing the code), this seem to be solved simply by changing the first if statement in updateCalendar to `if(startTime > endTime && endTime.getHours != 0)`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  I'm working my through this and have added a custom menu, but I'm still working on that function.  I've set the time zone per your suggestion and even found an example on resetting values to zero.

The thing I'm stuck on (at the moment) is when I'm debugging, I'm getting an error: TypeError: endTime.getHours is not a function.  This seems to be local to line 63 in updateCalendar: for (var j = startTime.getHours(); j < endTime.getHours(); j++){
and line 21 in rostering: calendarValues = updateCalendar(times[i][0], times[i][1], calendarValues, 0)

Comment: Check the format of the times in your spreadsheet. I suspect they are something like plain text. You may need to re-write these values so they are in a date/time format. In my sheet, I used Format > Number > More formats > Custom number format and set it to HH:mm, although under Custom data and time formats, there is an option similar to yours displaying AM/PM. If that doesn't work, add the following code before the IF statement in updateCalendar: `Logger.log(startTime + "|" + endTime);` and post the response you get immediately before the error here (and if some work, post those as well).

Comment: Here is what I'm seeing in the debug log:
1:22:11 PM
Notice
Execution started
1:22:12 PM
Info
Sat Dec 30 1899 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)|true
1:22:12 PM
Error
TypeError: endTime.getHours is not a function
updateCalendar
@ 
rostering
@
I'm guessing that the date/time info it's pulling in is at fault.  I did use the format that you suggested as well.  I'll keep digging in the interim.

Comment: You're referencing the wrong cells. That log is actually showing you endTime (18:00) and that they are due to work on Monday (true). I'm guessing the code you've written to get your data is including the name column, or in your test sheet column A contains your start time.

Comment: Ok, I'm 99% of the way there. I added the custom menu to run the script. I also added some script to clear all the cell values using `ClearCells`. Currently, the user has to run this from the menu before calculation. That said, the only place where I'm stuck is that on the RosterOverview tab, all of the "counted" instances generate a "1". Meaning, if there are 5 people working 9am on Monday, the output is this: "11111". This holds true for every non-zero value. It's probably something simple, but it looks like we're sending over a string, so I'm not sure how to parse that to count each 1.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to figure it out.  I changed my reset method from `ClearCells` to setting a "0" value using `setValue` for the given range, and it works like a charm.  Thank you!